# Разве / ` = надо преобразовывать в html-сущности?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Тут наткнулся на библиотеку [mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/blob/master/mustache.js#L60):

```
  var entityMap = {
    '&': '&amp;',
    '<': '&lt;',
    '>': '&gt;',
    '"': '&quot;',
    "'": '&#39;',
    '/': '&#x2F;', //  <--- НАФИГА???
    '`': '&#x60;', //  <--- НАФИГА???
    '=': '&#x3D;' //   <--- НАФИГА???
  };

  function escapeHtml (string) {
    return String(string).replace(/[&<>"'`=\/]/g, function fromEntityMap (s) {
      return entityMap[s];
    });
  }
```

Comment: а амперсанд и кавычки не смутили? :-)

Comment: то есть достаточно `<>` преобразовать? выходит `htmlspecialchars()` тоже лишнее преобразует? зачем?

Comment: Совсем по минимуму - это `<` и `&`. Чтобы "нигде ничего не упало" - ещё `>`, `/`, `"` и `'`. Конкретно `/` используется в самозакрывающихся тегах.

Comment: @Regent а `&` нафига и вправду? `<>` это понятно чтобы теги не разломать. `/` без `<>` тег не закроет.

Comment: Потому что `<`, например, преобразуется, в `&lt;`, а `&lt;` потом преобразуется обратно в `<`. А это что значит? Что когда браузер видит `&`, то считает, что дальше может идти некая последовательность, которую нужно преобразовать в символ. Поэтому если вы захотите в HTML-коде страницы сделать текст `&lt;` (именно такой текст, то есть чтобы он не преобразовывался в `<`), то придётся написать `&amp;lt;`. И хотя на практике такое вряд ли часто случается, но надеяться на авось не стоит.

Comment: Чёто я запутался с этим амперсандом. Добланная рекурсия. Мы преобразуем спец-символы в строки с амперсандом, амперсанд в которых мы преобразуем в строку с амперсандом... аррр

Comment: А чего тут путаться? Вот [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/4j7fyLwz/) этой ситуации. И, собственно, всё.

Comment: @Regent Ясно. Спасибо.